# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined error in 2d array

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

```
for (var i = 0; i < sipDates.length; i++) {

  var datepickerselector = "#" + sipDates[i][0] + "_txt_startdate";
  alert(datepickerselector);
  $(datepickerselector).datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    startDate: "today",
    autoclose: true,
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      //var dt_ddmmyyyy = date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear();
      var dt_ddmmyyyy = date.getDate().toString();
      if (sipDates.length > 0) {
        if (sipDates[i][1].indexOf(dt_ddmmyyyy) != -1) {
          return {
            tooltip: 'date',
            classes: 'active'
          };
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

I have an 2d array `sipDate` consist of customer id and dates (day) which will be enable in datepicker with respect to customer id but when I select any enabled date form datepicker it throws error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

below is image of whats inside `sipDateArray`
[image: sipDate array]

[image]

Comment: There is no `i` available in that place. With `beforeShowDay` you specify a callback function that runs much later, and your for loop is ancient history by then.